# Calendar date reverting to initialised date C#

Tags: c#, calendar

Here is my first piece of code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    visitDateCal.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; //defaults to today's date
}
```

I have this in my `Page_Load`. `visitDateCal` is a calendar. Whenever my calculate button is pressed, whatever is selected on the calendar is supposed to be stored in selectedDate control. Code below:

```
DateTime dateSelectedDateTime = visitDateCal.SelectedDate;
```

I then use that variable throughout the method. However if I change the date, then click my calculate button, the date reverts back to today's date? Help!

Comment: I assume this is ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: Yes sorry ASP.NET WebForms c#. Using web dev 2010

Comment: I think you need to put the code in the `Page_Load` method in a `!IsPostback` if block. `Page_Load` is called in postbacks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use IsPostBack Property of page.After that your code will look like this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        visitDateCal.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; //defaults to today's date
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Wow thank you! I've been trying solutions for this for hours and finally. Very fast response. Ups to you. Might have to use Stack Overflow more often.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback)
         visitDateCal.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today; //defaults to today's date
}
```

Page load is called on postback as well.Whenever the page object is created or recreated.

Comment: Happy to help. Welcome to SO! :)